# How to clear the Resource not found exception in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I got an exception (see below) while running my UWP application in the Release mode:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in SfDataGridDemo.McgInterop.dll
Additional information: ResourceMap Not Found.
```

Could anybody share the suggestion to resolve this.

Comment: Would you mind to share the code, which throws this exception? Without I dont think that it is possible to help you

Comment: I found that the exception throws while tried to read the .resw file, could you share your idea to resolve this

Comment: Please edit your post, with the lines of code which are  necessary to show how you try to read it. I will not start to guess what you are trying

Comment: Please add the full exception and the related code.
I guess, your app cannot find a file :)

Comment: Yea, you are correct, i have added the resource file as indirect child that's why i got that problem. if i add the file in my application as a dotect child it will working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Resource Map not found exception is due to retrieving of localization resources file and it is not possible to avoid this exception in WinRT/UWP platforms. But you can overcome this exception by including that resource file in your application/sample.

**Sample**: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/158877/ze/Localization-606413504

In the above sample, we have added the Resource file to avoid the exception.
You can get the default resource file from the below link

http://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfdatagrid/localization#editing-default-culture-resource